# Function with while loop no breaking

Tags: python

Here is the code:

```
def unnestList(l):
    result=[]
    for elem in l:
        while True:
            if not isinstance(elem,list):
                break
            else:
                for e in elem:
                    if isinstance(e,list):
                        elem = e[:]
                        continue
                    else:
                        break
        result.append(elem)
    return result
```

So I'm trying to unnest(sorry if it's not the correct word) a list of irregular lists.
Sample input:

```
[['A','B'],[['A']]]
[[['A', 'B', 'C']], [[[['A', 'D', 'E', 'B', 'C']]]]]
```

Expected output:

```
[['A','B'],['A']]
[['A', 'B', 'C'],['A', 'D', 'E', 'B', 'C']]
```

Comment: What's supposed to happen in that `while True` loop after the `for` loop finishes?  The `break` inside the `for` only breaks the `for`, not the outer `while`!

Comment: Oh, thanks. Any idea how I can stop the while loop inside the for?

Comment: I'm not sure your "unnesting" operation is fully specified. Are you just trying to eliminate one-element lists that contain other lists? Or does the top-level behave differently than inner levels (e.g. only it can contain multiple inner lists of different depths)?

Comment: The only way to stop an outer loop from inside an inner loop is to raise an exception -- a simpler solution would just be to have another `break` outside the `for` loop.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `while True` loop doesn't have a terminating condition in all cases.  Removing it completely (as in Kfir Ram's answer) seems to fix the problem for your sample inputs, but doesn't handle deeper nesting.

A recursive solution would be a little easier to follow IMO:

```
>>> def unnest_list(obj):
...     if not isinstance(obj, list):
...         return obj
...     if len(obj) == 1 and isinstance(obj[0], list):
...         return unnest_list(obj[0])
...     return [unnest_list(i) for i in obj]
...
>>> unnest_list([[[[[[['A']]]]]], [[[[[['B']]]]]]])
[['A'], ['B']]
```

Comment: Thank you, I thought about doing it recursively, but I don't think I'm at a level where i can do it as well as you did.

Comment: Doing this iteratively is the "advanced" solution to this kind of problem IMO; for anything involving arbitrarily nested structures, recursion tends to be the easy way.  If the recursive solution doesn't make sense to you, step through it line by line with some sample inputs.  The key to recursion is that the function doesn't need to solve the whole problem all at once; it just needs to solve the absolute easiest version of it (like in that first `if` statement), *or* reduce the problem a little bit (like in the last line) to get it closer to the easiest version.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Removing the while True loop seems to make it just fine.

```
def unnestList(l):
    result=[]
    for elem in l:
        if not isinstance(elem,list):
            break
        else:
            for e in elem:
                if isinstance(e,list):
                    elem = e[:]
                else:
                    break
        print(elem)
        result.append(elem)
    return result
```

[image]

Edit: seems like it still doesn't work for a nested list.

Second edit: Samwise helped you already :)

Comment: This doesn't work for more deeply nested lists though -- try e.g. `unnestList([[[[[['A']]]]]])`